# Issue with DJI SDK

Tags: sdk, dji-sdk

I have downloaded the GEO system application code and also registred our app to the DJI Developer Program have have changed the app key into code but the SDK is still not connecting.

It is showing an error every time we start the mission and stop mission. Is there anything which I also need to test.

Any ideas what I need to run this application into the device and test it with?

Please find the screenshot of the error attached.

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

I guess you haven't connected the DJI Product with the GEODemo application successfully, since I saw the **Mode**, **Speed**, **Altitude data** on the top in the screenshot are still not valid data. If you are using iOS 10, please try to enable the **Data Protection** in your Xcode project and try again, check [this FAQ](https://developer.dji.com/mobile-sdk/documentation/faq/index.html#application-registration-fail-in-ios-10-how-to-fix-it)

Hope this help!

Answer (score 0):

I too was facing this issue, this might be related to the mission manager instance. In their new SDK release to use mission manager we have to get its shared instance we can not create out own . You can look at this thread http://forum.dev.dji.com/thread-32614-1-1.html. Hope this solve your problem.